# triming url for starting dashes and ending extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have the following URL (originally generated from SEO toolin OS Commerce)

> http://www.mydomain.com/-some-name-s-34567.html

i want it to be displayed in browser as

> http://www.mydomain.com/some-name

i am already using this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-s-(.*).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

i want to drop -s--34567.html and  '-' before 'somename'

how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^-(some-name)-s-.*\.html$ "/$1" [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-s-(.*).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: @NewBee you want to do this only for "-some-name-s-*.html" or any such URL?

Comment: there are other categories too, like -p- , -c- etc, each reffers to differnt page

Comment: @NewBee basically you have to use parentheses. The first set of parenthese is $1, the second $2, and so on. Read up on regex.

Comment: @NewBee Do you want to go to product_info.php as well? How can you have both? You'll have to be more specific about your requirements.

Comment: i want to <li> redirect to specific page (product_info**) <li> my url should be simple as asked in question